# How to combine Testcontainers with @DataJpaTest avoiding code duplication?

Tags: java, junit5, spring-test, testcontainers

I want to use Testcontainers with `@DataJpaTest` (and `@SpringBootTest`) using JUnit 5. I have the basic setup working using the `@Testcontainers` and `@Container` annotation like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Testcontainers
public class AtleteRepositoryTest {
    @Container
    private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> CONTAINER = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:11");

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", CONTAINER::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", CONTAINER::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", CONTAINER::getPassword);
    }

    @Autowired
    private AtleteRepository repository;

    @Test
    void testSave() {
        repository.save(new Atlete("Wout Van Aert", 0, 1, 0));

        assertThat(repository.count()).isEqualTo(1);
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/blog-example-code/tree/feature/testcontainers-datajpatest/testcontainers-datajpatest for the full example code ([AtleteRepositoryTest](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/blog-example-code/blob/feature/testcontainers-datajpatest/testcontainers-datajpatest/src/test/java/com/wimdeblauwe/examples/testcontainersdatajpatest/atlete/AtleteRepositoryTest.java), [TeamRepositoryTest](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/blog-example-code/blob/feature/testcontainers-datajpatest/testcontainers-datajpatest/src/test/java/com/wimdeblauwe/examples/testcontainersdatajpatest/team/TeamRepositoryTest.java) and [TestcontainersDatajpatestApplicationTests](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/blog-example-code/blob/feature/testcontainers-datajpatest/testcontainers-datajpatest/src/test/java/com/wimdeblauwe/examples/testcontainersdatajpatest/TestcontainersDatajpatestApplicationTests.java)).

To avoid the repetition of declaring the PostgreSQL container and the dynamic properties, I tried the following:

## JUnit 5 extension

Baeldung has a blog about how you can [use a JUnit 5 extension to avoid the duplication](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dynamicpropertysource#an-alternative-test-fixtures).

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

public class PostgreSQLExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

    private PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres;

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:11");

        postgres.start();
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", postgres.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", postgres.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", postgres.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        postgres.stop();
    }
}
```

It works if you only have 1 test, but *not* if you run multiple at the same time (using IntelliJ or with Maven). In that case, one of the tests will fail because there is no connection with the database that can be made.
Also note that this extension does *not* use the `DynamicPropertyRegistry`, but plain environment variables.
See the [feature/testcontainers-datajpatest_baeldung-extension](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/blog-example-code/tree/feature/testcontainers-datajpatest_baeldung-extension/testcontainers-datajpatest) branch for the code.

## Using a common superclass

On the branch [feature/testcontainers-datajpatest_database-base-test](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/blog-example-code/tree/feature/testcontainers-datajpatest_database-base-test/testcontainers-datajpatest/src/test/java/com/wimdeblauwe/examples/testcontainersdatajpatest), I tried using a common superclass:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

public class DatabaseBaseTest {
    private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> CONTAINER = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:11");

    @BeforeAll
    static void start() {
        CONTAINER.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void stop() {
        CONTAINER.stop();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", () -> {
            String jdbcUrl = CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl();
            System.out.println("jdbcUrl = " + jdbcUrl);
            return jdbcUrl;
        });
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", CONTAINER::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", CONTAINER::getPassword);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that also does not work. I noticed in the logging that the `@DynamicPropertySource` annotated method was only called once and not for each test, which led me to try option 3:

## Common superclass with `@DynamicPropertySource` in subclasses

When using the common superclass, but adding the `@DynamicPropertySource` method in each subclass, it works again.

Example code of such a subclass:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class AtleteRepositoryTest extends DatabaseBaseTest {

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", () -> {
            String jdbcUrl = CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl();
            System.out.println("jdbcUrl = " + jdbcUrl);
            return jdbcUrl;
        });
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", CONTAINER::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", CONTAINER::getPassword);
    }

    @Autowired
    private AtleteRepository repository;

    @Test
    void testSave() {
        repository.save(new Atlete("Wout Van Aert", 0, 1, 0));

        assertThat(repository.count()).isEqualTo(1);
    }
}
```

See branch [feature/testcontainers-datajpatest_database-base-test_subclasses](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/blog-example-code/tree/feature/testcontainers-datajpatest_database-base-test_subclasses/testcontainers-datajpatest) for that version.

So while it works, there is still a lot of duplication in each test class.

Are there any other options for avoiding the duplication?

Comment: Do you need access to `PostgreSQLContainer` instance in your tests? With Spring Boot it is sufficient just to set `spring.datasource.url` to `jdbc:tc:postgresql:9.6.8:///databasename` and the right datasource will be picked up by `@DataJpaTest` and `@SpringBootTest`. The jdbc url `jdbc:tc...` indicates that this is a Testcontaienr and the right container will be started automatically. Here is the official documentation https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/

Comment: I am aware of that special JDBC URL syntax, but I would like a more generic solution so it can be used for other types of containers as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To avoid Testcontainers code repetition I generally follow 2 approaches:

1. Using **ApplicationContextInitializer** with **@ContextConfiguration**

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.test.util.TestPropertyValues;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

@Slf4j
public class PostgreSQLContainerInitializer
        implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    private static PostgreSQLContainer sqlContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:10.7");

    static {
        
        sqlContainer.start();
    }

    public void initialize (ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext){
        TestPropertyValues.of(
                "spring.datasource.url=" + sqlContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                "spring.datasource.username=" + sqlContainer.getUsername(),
                "spring.datasource.password=" + sqlContainer.getPassword()
        ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }

}
```

```java
import com.sivalabs.myservice.common.PostgreSQLContainerInitializer;
import com.sivalabs.myservice.entities.User;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.Optional;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {PostgreSQLContainerInitializer.class})
class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    void shouldReturnUserGivenValidCredentials() {
        User user = new User(null, "test@gmail.com", "test", "Test");
        entityManager.persist(user);
        
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.login("test@gmail.com", "test");
        
        assertThat(userOptional).isNotEmpty();
    }
}
```

2. Using **@DynamicPropertySource** in **Java 8+ Interface**

```java
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

@Testcontainers
public interface PostgreSQLContainerInitializer {

    @Container
    PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:12.3");

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerPgProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgres::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgres::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgres::getPassword);
    }
}
```

```java
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class UserRepositoryTest implements PostgreSQLContainerInitializer {

    ....
    ....
}
```

With these approaches we don't have to repeat **PostgreSQLContainer** declarations and Spring property settings.

Whether to use **PostgreSQLContainer** as a **static** field or not depends on whether you want to spin up a new container for every test or 1 container per test class.

**PS:**
I avoided using common base class approach because sometime one test needs only 1 container and another test needs multiple containers. If we follow add all the containers in common base class then for every test/class all those containers will be started irrespective of their usage which makes tests very slow.

Comment: After testing both approaches, I found that both approaches work for a single test, but only approach 1 works fine if you have many tests. I am using approach 1 now for my test suite. Thank you!

Comment: Great question and answer. IMHO, approach 2 is quite ingenious but it uses interfaces in a way that they were not meant to be used - approach 1 seems to be more correct